# Does istream_iterator reuse object?

Tags: c++, c++14, istream, istream-iterator

I'm writing a C++ library to parse WARC files, it contains the classes to store the WARC record and fields data as well as the operator to read the data from some input stream. It has the `operator>>` to read from a `istream` and populate the `WARCRecord` object. I'm able to read from the `istream` stream and parse it to a `WARCRecord` object. However, I would like to use a `istream_iterator` to read all the WARC records from the input stream.

When I use the `istream_iterator` to iterate until the end of the stream my [`operator>>`](https://github.com/jvanz/libwarc/blob/master/src/warc.cc#L58) receives the same(copy?) object of the last call. Is this the expected behavior or I'm missing some operator/constructor in my class definition?

This is the repository link with unit test to check this behavior: https://github.com/jvanz/libwarc

A simple example to demonstrate the above text:

```
#include <iostream>          
#include <istream>           
#include <sstream>           
#include <vector>            
#include <iterator>          


class MyClass                
{                            
        public:              
                std::vector<unsigned int> fields;          
        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, MyClass& obj);                                              

}; 



std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, MyClass& obj){ 
        std::istream::sentry s(is);                        
        if (s) {             
                for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++) {         
                        unsigned f;                        
                        is >> f;                           
                        obj.fields.push_back(f);           
                }            
        }                    
        return is;           
}                            

int main(void)               
{                            
        std::stringstream ss;                              
        ss << 1 << " " << 2 << " " << 3 << "  " << 4 << " " << 5 << " " << 6;                                          
        std::istream_iterator<MyClass> it(ss);             
        std::cout << it->fields.size() << std::endl;       
        it++;                
        std::cout << it->fields.size() << std::endl;       
        return 0;            
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
$ ./a.out 
3
6
```

Notice the accumulation of the `fields` member size of the `MyClass` object

Comment: It's unspecified whether an iterator of `std::istream_iterator<T>` will create a new object of `T` everytime the iterator is incremented. So an implementation may reuse the same internal object everytime for the read, and return it when dereferenced

Comment: Paste the code here instead of linking to it. Make sure it is a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stream_operator.h` from my machine to take a look in the `istream_iterator` class. As far as I could see, in fact, the class reuses the same object.

```
 /// Provides input iterator semantics for streams.                                                                                                                                                                                          
  template<typename _Tp, typename _CharT = char,                                                                                                                                                                                              
           typename _Traits = char_traits<_CharT>, typename _Dist = ptrdiff_t>                                                                                                                                                                
    class istream_iterator                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    : public iterator<input_iterator_tag, _Tp, _Dist, const _Tp*, const _Tp&>                                                                                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    public:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      typedef _CharT                         char_type;                                                                                                                                                                                       
      typedef _Traits                        traits_type;                                                                                                                                                                                     
      typedef basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits> istream_type;                                                                                                                                                                                    

    private:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      istream_type*     _M_stream;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      _Tp               _M_value;                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      bool              _M_ok;                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    public:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      ///  Construct end of input stream iterator.                                                                                                                                                                                            
      _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR istream_iterator()                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      : _M_stream(0), _M_value(), _M_ok(false) {}                                                                                                                                                                                             

      ///  Construct start of input stream iterator.                                                                                                                                                                                          
      istream_iterator(istream_type& __s)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      : _M_stream(std::__addressof(__s))                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      { _M_read(); }                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

      istream_iterator(const istream_iterator& __obj)                                                                                                                                                                                         
      : _M_stream(__obj._M_stream), _M_value(__obj._M_value),                                                                                                                                                                                 
        _M_ok(__obj._M_ok)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      { }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

      const _Tp&                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      operator*() const                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        __glibcxx_requires_cond(_M_ok,                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                _M_message(__gnu_debug::__msg_deref_istream)                                                                                                                                                                  
                                ._M_iterator(*this));                                                                                                                                                                                         
        return _M_value;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

      const _Tp*                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      operator->() const { return std::__addressof((operator*())); }                                                                                                                                                                          

      istream_iterator&                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      operator++()                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        __glibcxx_requires_cond(_M_ok,                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                _M_message(__gnu_debug::__msg_inc_istream)                                                                                                                                                                    
                                ._M_iterator(*this));                                                                                                                                                                                         
        _M_read();                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        return *this;                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      } 

 istream_iterator                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      operator++(int)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        __glibcxx_requires_cond(_M_ok,                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                _M_message(__gnu_debug::__msg_inc_istream)                                                                                                                                                                    
                                ._M_iterator(*this));                                                                                                                                                                                         
        istream_iterator __tmp = *this;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        _M_read();                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        return __tmp;                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

      bool                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      _M_equal(const istream_iterator& __x) const                                                                                                                                                                                             
      { return (_M_ok == __x._M_ok) && (!_M_ok || _M_stream == __x._M_stream); }                                                                                                                                                              

    private:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      void                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      _M_read()                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        _M_ok = (_M_stream && *_M_stream) ? true : false;                                                                                                                                                                                     
        if (_M_ok)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
          {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            *_M_stream >> _M_value;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            _M_ok = *_M_stream ? true : false;                                                                                                                                                                                                
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    };
```

Notice the `_M_read()` does not create new object before call the `operator>>`